# Why does ALTER command not work with sqlalchemy but works in pgAdmin?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, pgadmin

I'm definitely not an expert with SQL or sqlalchemy; I've used them quite a bit only doing basic CRUD activity. But now I'm using sqlalchemy to reset the index sequence on a number of tables:

```
table_sequences = {
    "pump_calendar_event":'pump_calendar_event_index_seq',
    "pump_calendar_rule":'pump_calendar_rule_index_seq',

}

for table,seq_name in table_sequences.items():
    max_index_query = f'SELECT MAX(index)+1 from public."{table}";'
    max_index_results = connection.execute(max_index_query).fetchall()[0][0]
    if max_index_results is not None:
        update_sequence_query = f'ALTER SEQUENCE "{seq_name}" RESTART WITH {max_index_results};'
        connection.execute(update_sequence_query)
        print(update_sequence_query)
```

`max_index_results` executes correctly and returns the highest index +1. But `connection.execute(update_sequence_query)` does not execute correctly. If it's failing then it's failing silently because I don't get an error. I know the query I generate is correct because I just copy and paste it into the query tool in pgAdmin and it resets the sequence. In short: it works when I copy and paste it manually but not when I run it with `connection.execute(update_sequence_query)`.

Comment: Are you using explicit transaction handling, or leave it to SQLA autocommit?

Comment: I'm not sure When I copy/paste into pgAdmin I just press the execute button. If you're referring to how I do it in Python - it's all in the code there. Am I missing something?